# Error "The parameter keyVaultCsmId has an invalid value" while adding App Service Certificates to KeyVault

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate, azure-keyvault

I have generated a wildcard certificate using Azure's App Service Certificate.

After this Azure asks you to configure the certificate in a KeyVault, and this is where I am getting stuck.

I have a Keyvault which is in the same region, same subscription, same resource group.

I have the necessary permissions to the key vault. I am a User Admin, Cert officer, Secrets officer, contributor to the key vault .

This step is failing with an error

```
Failed to link certificate with the selected Key Vault. Check below errors for more detail.
```

The Activity Log under App Service Certificate shows :

Operation Name : Add or Update Certificate

Status : Failed

Summary :

```
Operation name : Add or Update Certificate

Time stamp : Tue Jan 19 2021 07:10:46 GMT+1100 (Australian Eastern Daylight Time)

Event initiated by: xxxx

Error code: BadRequest

Message : The parameter keyVaultCsmId has an invalid value.
```

The JSON has the following important information :

```
"authorization": {
"action": "Microsoft.CertificateRegistration/certificateOrders/certificates/write",
"scope": "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/yyyyyyy/providers/Microsoft.CertificateRegistration/certificateOrders/InternalWildCard/certificates/InternalWildCard"
}

"properties": {
"statusCode": "BadRequest",
"serviceRequestId": null,
"statusMessage": "{\"Code\":\"BadRequest\",\"Message\":\"The parameter keyVaultCsmId has an invalid value.\",\"Target\":null,\"Details\":[{\"Message\":\"The parameter keyVaultCsmId has an invalid value.\"},{\"Code\":\"BadRequest\"},{\"ErrorEntity\":{\"ExtendedCode\":\"51008\",\"MessageTemplate\":\"The parameter {0} has an invalid value.\",\"Parameters\":[\"keyVaultCsmId\"],\"Code\":\"BadRequest\",\"Message\":\"The parameter keyVaultCsmId has an invalid value.\"}}],\"Innererror\":null}",
"eventCategory": "Administrative",
"entity": "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.CertificateRegistration/certificateOrders/InternalWildCard/certificates/InternalWildCard",
"message": "Microsoft.CertificateRegistration/certificateOrders/certificates/write",
"hierarchy": "xxxx"
    }
```

Any help on this or direction you can provide will be really appreciated :)

Answer (score 4):

Stuff which I didn't mention in the original question..

1. The existing key vault Permission Model is using RBAC for policies which is in preview [ Azure role-based access control (preview) ].
2. It has "Selected Networks" open and allows Trusted MS Networks..
3. It already has another wildcard cert in it as a secret ( different name )

I temporarily switched the Key Vault Permission Model to Vault access policy, and tried linking - and it worked.

Looks like a bug with the Permission Model using Azure RBAC.

Answer (score 3):

There should be a service principal in the Azure AD, if not you can create it.

Get-AzADServicePrincipal -DisplayName microsoft.azure.certificateregistration

You need to assign that permission to keyvault via either access policies OR RBAC.

Comment: Once I granted this service principal access over the key vault, I was able to configure key vault. Thank you. Do you know how this service principal is created? is it created automatically when you create app service certificate order or not?

Comment: I believe it is one of the many out of the box Provider owned SP's in the tenant.

I have worked with other similar SP's for things like Azure Front Door, where the registration was not in the tenant and I had to create it via the GUID myself.

I assume this would be the same.

Often you will find instructions for such listed in the specific provider documentation.

Answer (score 3):

#### Azure Key Vault RBAC (with Azure role-base access control) ❌

is not compatible with App Service Certificates.

#### Azure Key Vault with access policies method ✔️

is compatible with App Service Certificates.

You need to either change the access model to "access policies" or (if you don't have permission to change the access model) create a new Key Vault with access policy.

[image]

The documentation mentions this limitation.
[image]

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/rbac-migration#vault-access-policy-to-azure-rbac-migration-steps:~:text=Custom%20role%20required-,Note,-Azure%20App%20Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/rbac-migration#vault-access-policy-to-azure-rbac-migration-steps:%7E:text=Custom%20role%20required-,Note,-Azure%20App%20Service)

Comment: Switched from RBAC to access policies and this worked. Even converted my RBAC roles over to policies.

Answer (score 0):

In Azure Key Vault, supported certificate formats are PFX and PEM.

• .pem file format contains one or more X509 certificate files.

• .pfx file format is an archive file format for storing several cryptographic objects in a single file i.e. server certificate (issued for your domain), a matching private key, and may optionally include an intermediate CA.

Certificates used by App Service first needs to be converted to (and marked as) application/x-pkcs12. Re-importing the cert from a pfx file with the --password parameter (az keyvault certificate import), and after that import it from the key vault to the webapp might help. You may refer to this Blog might be helpful.

Also, look if Cert and the Key Vault are in their original resource group.

Additional details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/certificates/tutorial-import-certificate

https://azure.github.io/AppService/2016/05/24/Deploying-Azure-Web-App-Certificate-through-Key-Vault.html

Comment: So I have generated the cert using App Service Certificate service of Azure - I didn't see any option to set the content-type / or the type of file while linking it to the keyvault.

Comment: Edit my comment, hopes this helps

Comment: Hi thanks.
I tried selecting the option of provisioning a new keyvault and it worked. So I don't think the format is an issue...
1. The existing keyvault is using RBAC for policies which is in preview.
2. It has "Selected Networks" open and allows Trusted MS Networks..
3. It already has another wildcard cert in it as a secret ( different name )

Any one of the above might be an issue in this case... that's what I am guessing.

Comment: So yea looks like it's a bug with Azure role-based access control (preview) in KeyVault.
As soon as I switched the Access policies to use the Vault Access Policy - it started working.

Thanks!!

Comment: Thats good to hear, please mark the answer to close the topic

Answer (score 0):

After battling with it for hours this is what I did to work:

Open PowerShell.

1.
Get {AppID}

Get-AzADServicePrincipal -DisplayName microsoft.azure.certificateregistration

2.
New-AzRolAssignment -RoleDefinitionName "Key Vault Secrets Officer" -ApplicationId {AppID}

Answer (score -1):

To fix the issue:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/quickstarts/microsoft.web/app-service-certificate-standard

By default, 'Microsoft.CertificateRegistration' and 'Microsoft.Web' RPs don't have access to the Key Vault specified in the template hence you need to authorize these RPs by executing the following PowerShell commands before deploying the template:

```
Login-AzureRmAccount
Set-AzureRmContext -SubscriptionId AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName KEY_VAULT_NAME -ServicePrincipalName f3c21649-0979-4721-ac85-b0216b2cf413 -PermissionsToSecrets get,set,delete
Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName KEY_VAULT_NAME -ServicePrincipalName abfa0a7c-a6b6-4736-8310-5855508787cd -PermissionsToSecrets get
```

ServicePrincipalName parameter represents these RPs in user tenant and will remain same for all Azure subscriptions. This is a onetime operation. Once you have a configured a Key Vault properly, you can use it to store as many App Service Certificates as you want without executing these PowerShell commands again.